# How do I turn off the News?

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm trying to play a few Cash Run tracks, but every time I find a start point I get this message:

[image: Cryptic Message]

And when I check my phone:

[image: Blocked App]

What does this mean? It doesn't seem like a News Alert is going on, I don't see anything on nearby screens or hear anything.

How do I turn off this News Alert?